# Show open Price line only for today

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

As in the picture shows the pink line is the open price. I would like this to show just for today and doesn't extend backward. Is this possible somehow? I couldn't find a good answer here for such problem. [image]
Here is my code:

```
study("Today Open Yesterday Close", overlay=true)
tdo = security(tickerid, 'D', open) // today
plot(tdo,linewidth=1,color=maroon)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
study("Today Open Yesterday Close", overlay=true)
tdo = security(tickerid, 'D', open) // today

isToday = false
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true


plot(tdo,linewidth=1,color=isToday ? maroon : na)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. thank you bbnm

Comment: Now sure if you know this but is it possible to plot only the graph and set the text that appear to the top left of the screen to false?